# Using only CSS, show the last 3 letters of the text inside an HTML5 element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have an element with fixed width and height, how can I show only the *last 3 letters* of the text inside an HTML5 element instead of the *first 3 letters*?

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

Ellipses did not work. I am trying to achieve this *without* JavaScript.

Is there a CSS only solution?

Comment: `display:flex; justify-content: flex-end;` for the container element also does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `float: right;` to the `span` will do that

Stack snippet

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

---

Or `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;` on the `.box`

Stack snippet

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `direction: rtl;`

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
 direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    var res = str.slice(-3);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
window.onload = myFunction;
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span id="demo"></span>
</div>
```